# How to identify the view which is being pinch zoomed in Android?

Tags: android, textview, pinchzoom

I have implemented pinch zoom for a TextView using the below code. 
But, with the code TextView zooms even when a user pinches anywhere on the screen. I need to make the pinch zoom work only when the TextView is pinched. 
Could someone help me out?

My existing code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   // return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (event.getPointerCount() == 2)
    {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int pureaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        if (pureaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
        {
            mBaseDist = getDistance(event);
            mBaseRatio = mRatio;
        }
        else
        {
            float delta = (getDistance(event) - mBaseDist) / STEP;
            float multi = (float) Math.pow(2, delta);
            mRatio = Math.min(1024.0f, Math.max(0.1f, mBaseRatio * multi));
            mTextView.setTextSize(mRatio + 13);
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setOnTouchListener` and override `onTouch` method, which will give view being touched.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //v is view touched
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView YOUR_TEXTVIEW = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);    

YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          //Your Code
       }
    });
```

Condition For View Touch

```
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          if(v.getId() == R.id.textView){
            //Your Code
          }
       }
```